# codeigniter 3 issue with fetch session ID

Tags: codeigniter

i want check session and get current user details only one row i new here plz help

```
   public function profile() {
        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->model('brid_groom_fetch');
        $this->session->userdata('uname');

        //This  below line fetch model db data
        $row = $this->brid_groom_fetch->get_program_specific_gender();

        //here i have check data is in session..
        $session_id = $this->session->userdata(
         array('uname' => $row->uname));
         print_r($sesid);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use basic `==` operator ?

```
public function __construct() {

    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('brid_groom_fetch');

    // you need to load session library
    // Have you loaded ?
    $this->load->library('session');
}


public function profile() {

    $this->load->view('header');

    // you do not need to load in all method.
    // we have already loaded in __construct()
    // $this->load->model('brid_groom_fetch');

    // use variable 
    $uname = $this->session->userdata('uname');

    //fetch data from db
    $row = $this->brid_groom_fetch->get_program_specific_gender();

    if ($row->uname == $uname) {
        $session_id = $this->session->userdata('session_id');
        var_dump($session_id);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply but sir it has been given an error Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: anyone can give solution to this quation

Answer (score 0):

You are setting userdata with

```
$this->session->set_userdata(array('uname' => $yourname));
```

or

```
$this->session->set_userdata('uname',$yourname);
```

To check what value is set in the userdata you need to use

```
$sess_name = $this->session->userdata('uname');
print_r($sess_name);
```

And then validate this $sess_name you have received.
You can also unset the userdata by using

```
$this->session->unset_userdata('uname');
```